# data lag in sqlserver 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I want to calculate data lag in sqlserver 2005 between primary and mirror server.will calculating of lsn(logical sequence no) on both sides will be helpful.if yes how i can calculate lsn no .please describe the whole process.I am too much confused.

it would be a great help.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question what you mean by "lag" - do you mean the additional latency introduced by mirroring for the transaction running on the master, or the time elapsed before a transaction applied on the master is applied on the mirror?
This answer assumes you mean the second of those options.

If you're using synchronous mirroring (`TRANSACTION SAFETY = ON` - the only version available in SQL 2005 Standard Edition) then there is no lag - the transaction is not committed at the master until a successful write at the mirror is confirmed - therefore both databases are always in sync.

Asynchronous mirroring (`TRANSACTION SAFETY = OFF`) is only available in Enterprise Edition and above - the easiest way to monitor latency is using the Database Mirroring Monitor.

There are also a number of Performance Monitor counters which can be used to get info about mirroring see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189931%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx